What is $Arg(\frac{z}{w})$ if $Arg(z) = -\frac{5\pi}{6}$ and $Arg(w) = \frac{\pi}{4}$?
The problem:
If $Arg(z) = -\frac{5\pi}{6}$ and $Arg(w) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, find $Arg(\frac{z}{w})$.
The answer:
$\frac{11\pi}{12}$
What I have tried:
$Arg(\frac{z}{w}) = Arg(z) - Arg(w) = -\frac{5\pi}{6} - \frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{10\pi}{12} - \frac{3\pi}{12} = -\frac{13\pi}{12}$
What is it I am doing wrong? Why am I not getting the right answer?

The argument of a complex number is restricted in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

$\arg(z/w) = \arg(z) - \arg(w)$ only holds up to a multiple of $2 \pi$, you will want to add $2 \pi$ to the answer you get

I'm confused. What method am I to use instead?

Hints:

Convert $\arg z = \bigg (-\dfrac {5 \pi}{6} \bigg )$ to a positive angle, then subtract this positive angle from $\arg w.$
Use George Coote's hint (i.e. find the complementary angle of $-\dfrac {11 \pi}{6}$ by adding $2 \pi$)


Isn't $Arg(w)$ meant to be subtracted from $Arg(z)$ and not the other way around?

Yes - the mechanics are correct, but I suggest you read my hints (and Abd-Elouahab Moustapha's answer) to understand where you went wrong.

we have :
$$arg(z)=\{Arg(z)+2n\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
where$$-\pi<Arg(z)\le \pi$$
therfore:
$$arg(z)=\{\frac{-5\pi}{6}+2n\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
$$arg(w)=\{\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
we have :
$$arg(z/w)=arg(z)-arg(w)=\{Arg(z)-Arg(w)+2n\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
$$arg(z/w)=\{-\frac{13\pi}{12}+2n\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\{2\pi-\frac{13\pi}{12}+2(n-1)\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\{\frac{11\pi}{12}+2(n-1)\pi|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
Therfore:
$$Arg(z/w)=\frac{11\pi}{12}$$

definitely a fan of the multivalued approach myself, but this might be unfamiliar so it might be useful to explain

Please, do explain. Where is the $2nπ$ coming from? Where is the $2(n-1)$ coming from?
